# Is there a way to temporarily remove this old can light box?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have this old can light box that I need to temporarily remove to extend the circuit with one more light bulb that would to into a crawl space in the adjacent room.

I am counting on the fact that the opening is large enough to allow me to use a flexible fish drill bit to get a cable in that room without opening the ceiling

The problem is that I can't find a way to remove the box, it was probably installed before the basement ceiling was installed.

Note: I am using LED bulbs for these so probably the box does not need to be that big and that deep anymore to provide thermal insulation there (avoid heat transfer and fire hazard)

Here are some pictures, apparently the brand is Prescolite, model BX?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 darker colored sides will push outwards. If that is big enough opening you all set. If need the rest of box removed, you will have to work through the side openings to dismantle the remaining frame to lift out.

There is the possibility that can is "fire blocked" with drywall enclosure sealing it from attic space.

Comment: Thanks @Keith ...yes that could be more than enough ...is there a schematic diagram of this thing or an equivalent so I can understand better what you are talking about ?
This is a ceiling basement. I was thinking about using a rotary tool (Dremel) to cut out an opening on the side ...No the box can stay where it is I do not want it removed

Comment: If you could find manufacturer and model#, could probably find pictures. From your pictures, can see the spring clips holding the sides in place. Pushing them out should allow access to the wiring box for the fixture, and the surrounding space.

Comment: got it thank you. I was wondering what those are for ..... I will give it a try. Worst case scenario I will cut the box with the rotary tool

Comment: If you have to drill a hole, you'll probably want to use one of those push-in cable connectors/gaskets in the hole.